# Не работает boost::regex_match

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь спарсить инклуды в .cpp файлах. Для их поиска прохожу по всему файлу и сравниваю строку с этим регэкспом:

```
boost::regex headerEx("#include *[<\"] *\\w+ *[>\"]");
```

и оно не работает, например, для строки

```
#include <iostream>
```

Компилятор - VC11

Сам код:

```
boost::regex headerEx("#include *[<\"] *\\w+ *[>\"]");
std::string line;
std::string header;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
        if(boost::regex_match(line, headerEx)) {
            int pos;
            if((pos = line.find("<")) != std::string::npos) {
                header = line.substr(pos + 1, line.find(">") - pos - 1);
            }
            else if((pos = line.find("\"")) != std::string::npos) {
                header = line.substr(pos + 1, line.find_last_of("\"") - pos - 1);
            }
            boost::algorithm::trim(header);
            std::cout << header << std::endl;
            //TODO: Вставить хедер в дерево, проверить на наличие и парсить хедеры на наличие других
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вроде должно работать. Дайте пример кода.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Изменил регулярку на 

    "^\\s*#\\s*include\\s+[<\"](.*?)\\s*[>\"].*?$"

и все заработало

Comment: Угу, видите, проблема с началами и концами строк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте, не содержит ли строка `line` символ перевода строки (`\n`) в конце? Дело в том, что [`boost::regex_match`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) проверяет, подходит ли *вся* строка `line` под регулярное выражение, а у вас `headerEx` не рассчитана на `\n` в конце.